# TuxOnIce hibernate error "seeking to free XXXXMB of memory" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hibernate, swap, memory-usage, memory-leak, tuxonice

My desktop PC did not support for hibernate on Ubuntu 14.04. Therefore, I installed TuxOnIce (kernale `3.13.0-36-generic-tuxonice`) to enable hibernate feature. Now, the **hibernate feature works fine on low memory use** (with command `pm-hibernate`).

But, when I **hibernate my computer with too many applications open** (higher memory use, > 45% of total memory), I am getting error message saying **seeking to free XXXXMB of memory.**

I have a SWAP memory which is bigger than RAM memory, here are the details of my PC memory status:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         16018      10577       5441         77        211       3151
-/+ buffers/cache:       7215       8803
Swap:        17855          0      17855
```